# Donde debo de poner el codigo en Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

Soy nuevo en el tema por lo cual, les comento que no cuento con mucha práctica, hice una carpeta y dentro de ella están mis `Forms`, por lo cual no se si es allí donde le debo de meter el código,entre ellos mi barra de menú o en la `Web Master`, espero y me haya explicado, por cierto soy nuevo en `StackOverflow`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! A que codigo te referis?

Comment: cuando dices "meter el codigo", a que codigo te refieres?  es javascript o c# porque si es codigo del lado servidor va en el aspx.cs pero si es javascript va junto al html